# How can I improve my Haskell code and make it work?

Tags: list, haskell, fen

In my code I call the validateFEN function with a FEN String. A Fen string looks like this for example:

```
",w84,w41,w56,w170,w56,w41,w84,/,,w24,w40,w17,w40,w48,,/,,,w16,w16,w16,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,b1,b1,b1,,,/,,b3,b130,b17,b130,b129,,/,b69,b146,b131,b170,b131,b146,b69,"
```

The function should take the string and check if it's a FEN string.
How does it know if it's a FEN string? -> My string has 9 rows and 9 columns. I don't need to check if the pieces (example: w86) are at their right position.

```
validateFEN' b = help3 (filter (\x -> x == ',' || x == '/' ) b)

help3 b =  (if help1 b == True then (if head (drop 8 b) == '/' then help3 (drop 9 b) else False) else False )

help1 b = help2 (take 8 b)

help2 b = foldr (+) 0 (map (\x -> if x == ',' then 1 else 0 )b) == 8
```

Why do I keep getting the error for a empty list?

> Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

I understand that with my code there is no stop. The program doesn't know when the string is "correct".

Is there a shorter simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I'm struggling to make "Why do I keep getting the error for a empty list?" and "I understand that with my code there is no stop." make sense at the same time. Surely you just answered your own question? What's left for us to help with? Is this purely a code review request?

Comment: Never use `head`. Pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok I see instead of head what can I use to access the first element of a list?  I mean are there easier ways (like in java or scala) to iterate through a list?

Comment: Ist da etwa jemand von der TU Berlin?

Comment: @Snusqx That depends on what you want to happen if the list is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to reuse existing library functions to make this clearer would be to use `stripPrefix`.

```
help3 s = case stripPrefix ",,,,,,,,/" s of
    Nothing -> False
    Just s' -> help3 s'
```

Of course, you still need to handle the final case, where there is no terminating `/`. This can be done with a single extra clause:

```
help3 ",,,,,,,," = True
help3 s = {- ... -}
```

You might want to ponder whether `validateFEN'` should have a similar special case for the empty string.

BUT I would strongly suggest simply not implementing `validateFEN'` in the first place. My guess is that the plan is something like this:

1. Check if a string is valid FEN.
2. Process the string, assuming FEN-ness.

Instead, I recommend the following approach:

1. Parse the string into a native data structure that represents the information available in a FEN string.
2. Process the native structure.

Step 1, if written with standard parsing solutions, will "accidentally" validate the string -- i.e. running your parser will return something like `Either Error FEN`, which you can pattern match  on to either discover that the string is invalid or that it is valid and has been turned into a more idiomatic representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm still new to haskell I will look into it.